# USB-C cable PCB

Tags: pcb, usb, usb-c

I'm trying to emulate USB cable by FFC and Flat connectors ( I-PEX_20535-020E-02 ) but I don't know if it is possible use 2 layers for the pcb design. In TI Superspeed guides (SLLA414) they advice you route the lines over GND reference plane but I have cut a usb-c pcb and there only have 2 layers (no GND reference and overlap lines). Is this rule not critical for small pcbs like this? Or am i misunterstanding reference plane?

[image]

Comment: There's the standard, there's recommendations, and then there's what manufacturers actually do. You also get what you pay for.

Comment: @Passerby then it is a normal thing that manufacturers do they want, isn't it?

Comment: Some will make to spec. Some will do whatever gets them the dollar.

Comment: BTW, this little piece of PCB is called "paddle card" per USB Type-C specifications, section 3.2.2.5 It is always difficult to make things "good" and "cheap" at the same time.